# Rollup.js, Typescript and require()

Tags: typescript, commonjs, rollup, rollupjs

I'm trying to require an untyped module

config

```
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    format: 'es',
    file: 'dist/index.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    nodeResolve(),
    commonjs()
  ]
}
```

input

```
// index.ts
var f = require('untypedModule')
f()
```

output

```
// dist/index.js
var f = require('untypedModule')
f()
```

As you can see 'typescript-plugin' somehow prevents 'commonJs' and 'nodeResolve' to produce proper output

If I remove 'typescript-plugin' from chain, **the output is correct**.
commonJs plugin brings **content of module** and removes require call

Tried:

- change plugin order
- 'rollupCommonJSResolveHack' flag

I really want to 'require' untyped module,
because it works in webpack

Please help.

Comment: This is a big issue.  I'd like to use cycle.js and rollup, but it's not working because some of the cycle.js modules depend on untyped modules.

Comment: The discussion continued here
https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/43

Comment: My issue was particularly with cycle.js. they've added custom type definitions now!